# How do I use quoted identifier for user + table name combination in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, reserved-words, quoted-identifier

In my Oracle DB setup all the tables are created under dedicated user account `SYS0MYUSER`. When executing following query on my system I got `SQL Error: ORA-00903: invalid table name`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYS0MYUSER.USER;
```

I tried to escape the reserved keyword like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "SYS0MYUSER.USER";
```

But then I got another error `SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

What is the correct way to escape *user name* + *reserved keyword* combination ?

UPDATE:
What's about table alias do I have to use double quotes too ?

Comment: Find out what's the actual schema name. Is `SYS0MYUSER` the actual schema name?

Comment: @Rahul OP has mentioned the user is `SYS0MYUSER`. In Oracle, user and schema name are synonymous.

Comment: @tommyk - Is the table name `USER`?

Comment: @LalitKumarB Yes, the table name is USER.

Comment: @tommyk See my answer, updated to answer your question about table alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have created the table using **[quoted identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129)**, then you must always use **double-quotation marks** wherever you refer the object.

From documentation,

> Database Object Naming Rules
>
> Every database object has a name. In a SQL statement, you represent
>   the name of an object with a quoted identifier or a nonquoted
>   identifier.
>
> - A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you
>     must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.
> - A nonquoted identifier is not surrounded by any punctuation.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE "USER"(A NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LALIT.USER;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LALIT.USER
                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00903: invalid table name


SQL>
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LALIT."USER";

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

So, you need to refer the table as a **quoted identifier**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYS0MYUSER."USER";
```

**Update** OP updated his question regarding table alias.

> What's about table alias do I have to use double quotes too ?

**Table alias** has nothing to do with the quoted identifier.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT t.* FROM LALIT."USER" t;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "SYS0MYUSER"."USER";
```

Comment: How will you know `SYS0MYUSER` is the schema name?

Comment: No need of quoted identifier for the schema name.

Comment: It's never wrong to quote identifiers, even if they aren't reserved words. I'd say it's actually good practice to always double quote all identifiers, mainly because of portability and forward compatibility. (But I'm a bit lazy, so I don't do it always...)

Comment: *it's actually good practice to always double quote all identifiers* I don't agree with that. It would create more confusion for developers. Let's say a developer build a habit of using quoted identifiers, and then he uses a lower-case object name in his quoted identifier, he will get error `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`. With quoted-identifier the problem is that it makes it **case sensitive**.

Comment: How does Oracle chose between TableA and TABlea, if you do select * from TABLEA?

Comment: @jarlh All the three are same. There will never be a problem if you use nonquoted identifiers while creating objects. Problems start when you create objects using quoted identifiers.

Comment: Can you create both "TABlea", "TableA" and tablea as three separate tables?